# Bypass Cloudfare using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I just want to bypass the cloudfare service using selenium python I have made a code but it doesn't work

Here is my code:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features")
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r".\chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://poocoin.app/tokens/0xef2ec90e0b8d4cdfdb090989ea1bc663f0d680bf')
```

and when I run the code I will got stuck in cloudfare

See Screenshot:

[image]

when I open it manually it seems like this
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "but it doesn't work"?
The screen you see presented even if I open that link manually.

Comment: When i open it manually it will open perfectly

Comment: Hi, I have update the question, please check it hope you understand what i am trying to say

Answer (score 0):

I see that cloudfare screen too.
All that you need is to add a wait condition until the `poocoin` site itself is presented.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

wait.until(EC.url_to_be('https://poocoin.app/tokens/0xef2ec90e0b8d4cdfdb090989ea1bc663f0d680bf'))
```

After that you can continue with your flow.
You can wait to some other condition as well. For example `title to be` or presence of some element located on that page.

Comment: Its not work cuz the driver get stuck on cloudfare They will not go on actuall link

Comment: have you tried what I wrote? Have you defined the wait timeout?

Comment: WebDriverWait(driver, 1000).until(EC.url_to_be('https://poocoin.app/tokens/0xef2ec90e0b8d4cdfdb090989ea1bc663f0d680bf'))

Comment: I have set the timeout at 1000.

Comment: What is your code after `driver.get('https://poocoin.app/tokens/0xef2ec90e0b8d4cdfdb090989ea1bc663f0d680bf')` line presented here?

Comment: `WebDriverWait(driver,1000).until(EC.url_to_be('https://poocoin.app/tokens/0xef2ec900b8d4cdfdb090989ea1bc663f0d680bf'))`

Comment: And nothing after that?

Comment: nope because I just saw on driver chrome it only stuck on cloudfare

Comment: even also I store the page source but it doesn't getting the actual webpage html

Comment: When you say stuck on cloudfare. How long is it suck there? Because, again, I tried that several times. The cloudfare appears each time for me but it passed after several seconds.

Comment: IT will stuck for long time I have set the timeout on 1000 second and still the driver stuck on cloudfare

Comment: Really strange.. Again, I tried this myself several times and that screen passed after several seconds....

Comment: Can you please share the proper code which you are run on your laptop?

Comment: No, sorry. But there is really nothing special there

Comment: `driver.get('https://poocoin.app/tokens/0xef2ec90e0b8d4cdfdb090989ea1bc663f0d68bf')
WebDriverWait(driver,1000).until(EC.url_to_be('https://poocoin.app/tokens/0xef2ec90e0b8d4cdfdb090989ea1bc663f0d680bf'))

print(WebDriverWait(driver,1000).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//h1/following::span[1]'))).text)`

Comment: I have tried this code and its doesn't work

Comment: AFAIK WebDriverWait(driver,1000).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//h1/following::span[1]')) doesn't return element....

Comment: Yes They didn't return anything

Comment: So, you can't apply `text()` on it.  Just add some other code AFTER the wait condition